# Pushing a new value to array inside heredoc in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, heredoc

Assume I have this block of Bash code:

```
arr=(a b c)
sudo -i -u username bash <<EOF
  arr[${#arr[@]}]="d"
EOF
```

I need to add "d" to arr inside heredoc. But it is not working.

Comment: With the `sudo` command, you're launching another `bash` session. The "d" value is appended to the `arr` array in _that_ session, your array `arr` in the initial session is then **not** altered. Are you looking to source a shell script through `sudo` ?

Comment: Yes, it seems I have to define an internal variable and do modifications on it then.

Comment: `arr[${#arr[@]}]="d"` = `arr+=("d")`

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the context to another session.

```
arr=(a b c)
sudo -i -u username bash <<EOF
$(declare -p arr)
arr[\${#arr[@]}]="d"
EOF
```

or like:

```
arr=(a b c)
DATA=$(declare -p arr)
export DATA
sudo --preserve-env=DATA -i -u username bash <<'EOF'
eval "$DATA"
arr[${#arr[@]}]="d"
EOF
```